# Microsoft OcrEngine: Exception in recognizing image which contains Chinese text contents

Tags: ocr, windows-phone-8.1, chinese-locale

I'm developing an windows phone 8.1 app(not silverlight) about OCR with using [WindowsPreview.Media.Ocr].
I replaced the default OCR resouce file with chinese ocr resouce file.

Here's my code,in Constructor：

```
ocrEngine = new OcrEngine(OcrLanguage.ChineseSimplified);
```

and then load the test image with chinese text contents:

```
    private async Task LoadImage()
    {
        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("TestImages\\Test4.png");

        ImageProperties imgProp = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

        using (var imgStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)imgProp.Width, (int)imgProp.Height);
            bitmap.SetSource(imgStream);
            PreviewImage.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

and begin:

```
await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync((uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray());
```

at this line, an exception was thrown:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at OCRImgReadText.MainPage.<ExtractText_Click>d__f.MoveNext()
```

The code above runs perfectly with recognizing English contents image.
Could anybody give me some advice?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that including resources for both Chinese Simplified and English solves the issue.